# What does apc.file_md5 do (Alternative PHP Cache)?

Tags: php

I'm prompted to ask by [an answer to a related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/201690/can-apc-recognise-duplicate-source-files/201701#201701). In APC-3.1.1 there was introduced the new flag `apc.file_md5`. Does anyone know what it currently does, or maybe what it's intended to do in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got curious and went looking, the only reference I could find was located in the 3.1 release changelog, attributed to Brian Shire, shire@php.net. Maybe he'll take a moment to reply to an email :)

Comment: You know it never even occurred to me! Thanks, I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: I contacted Brian Shire and he said that it was developed as part of an internal push process to detect changed source files. So it _is_ just an md5 at the moment!

Comment: Whoa, nice! I might just enable that :)

Comment: Sorry, must've miscommunicated - currently it's _*only*_ an md5 - APC doesn't do anything with it. It's the first step to doing what I'm after tho, so maybe it'll come along...

Comment: Ah, right on, soon enough.